# Microsoft SQL Server - Who created a trace?

Tags: sql-server, trace

I need to find out who started a trace on one of our SQL Server instance

```
SELECT * FROM sys.traces
```

don't tell ...

Answer (score 2):

Trace start and stop events are recorded in the Windows System event log. This includes the user who started the trace.

You can view the log using Event Viewer (command line eventvwr.msc and then select Windows Logs-->System).

The Windows system log can also be viewed from within SSMS Object Explorer under Management-->SQL Server Logs. Double-click on Current and select Windows NT-->System.

The trace start message is also recorded in the SQL Server error log, which can similarly be viewed from SSMS or by viewing the SQL Server error log file(s) directly.

The retention of the SQL Server error logs vary depending on the number of service restarts. The retention of the Windows events depend on how the event log is configured, which is a capped size and overwrite as needed by default.

Note that the `default trace` (enabled by default) and `c2 audit mode` traces are configured with [sp_configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-configuration-options-sql-server).

Comment: The problem is, that this trace is running over a year+. We don't keep the event log information for so long :( .

Comment: @Winblows, I can't think of a way to get the creating user if the record has rolled out of the event log. Are you implying SQL Server hasn't been restart since the trace was created? Traces need to be recreated after every restart unless it's the default trace or created with the `c2 audit mode` configuration option.

Comment: the is 
[code]c2 audit mode[/code]
not set 
the 
SELECT * FROM sys.traces

Comment: @Winblows, SQL Server must be restarted before the `c2 audit mode` trace is created. The trace file name will reflect it's the audit trace in this case.

Comment: c2 audit mode was set to 1.
THANKS!

Comment: After restart of the SQL Server instance, the trace is gone! :)